# Cannot find symbol even with class imported

Tags: java

I have a bit of a weird situation.

The problem is with `import java.nio.*;` and `import java.nio.file.Paths;`.

First of all, `import java.nio.*;` should import the second class anyway, but I'm experiencing something weird. It might be a known mistake I'm making but I'm new to Java.

If I import both, or if I import only `java.nio.*`, I get `error: cannot find symbol` for `Files.write(...)`. However, if I import only `java.nio.file.Paths`, I get the same error but for `Paths.get(...)`.

Any idea as to why this is happening? I'm open to exploring other options than these two classes, all I want to do is append a text file.

```
public static void addAction(String cmd) {
  String text = "Text to save to file";
  Files.write(Paths.get("/Users/Andrew/Desktop/testfile.txt"), text.getBytes());
}
```

is the bit where the problem is, but in case it's a problem with something else that I wrote I've attached the whole file below:

```
import java.io.File; // Find Files

import java.awt.FileDialog; // File Picker

import javax.swing.JFrame; // JFrame

import java.nio.*;

// import java.nio.file.Paths;

class Files {

  public static void getApps(final File folder) {
      for (final File file : folder.listFiles()) {
              String fileName = file.getName();
              // System.out.println(fileName);
              // System.out.println(file.getPath());
              final File subfolder = new File(file.getPath()+"/Contents/Resources");
              if (subfolder.exists()) {
                String icon = pickFile(subfolder.getPath());
                if (icon == null) return;
                System.out.println("App Name: " + fileName);
                System.out.println("Icon Name: " + icon);
              } else {
                System.out.println("Directory not found...");
              }
      }
  }

  public static String pickFile(String path) {
    FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(new JFrame(), "Select File to Open");
    dialog.setMode(FileDialog.LOAD);
    dialog.setFilenameFilter((File dir, String name) -> name.endsWith(".icns"));
    dialog.setDirectory(path);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    String fileChosen = dialog.getFile();
    return fileChosen;
  }

  public static void addAction(String cmd) {
    String text = "Text to save to file";
    Files.write(Paths.get("/Users/Andrew/Desktop/testfile.txt"), text.getBytes());
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    String action = "{\n\"BTTTouchBarButtonName\":\"Messages\",\n\"BTTTriggerType\":629,\n\"BTTTriggerClass\":\"BTTTriggerTypeTouchBar\",\n\"BTTPredefinedActionType\":49,\n\"BTTPredefinedActionName\":\"Launch Application \\/ Open File \\/ Start Apple Script …\",\n\"BTTLaunchPath\":\"file:\\/\\/\\/Applications\\/Messages.app\",\n\"BTTEnabled2\":1,\n\"BTTUUID\":\"F3089B96-FDEF-4D54-9DA8-9CCD3C7AF8A9\",\n\"BTTEnabled\":1,\n\"BTTRequiredModifierKeys\":1048576,\n\"BTTOrder\":1,\n   \"BTTIconData\":\"icondata\",\n\"BTTTriggerConfig\":{\n\"BTTTouchBarItemIconHeight\":22,\n\"BTTTouchBarItemIconWidth\":22,\n\"BTTTouchBarItemPadding\":0,\n\"BTTTouchBarFreeSpaceAfterButton\":\"5.000000\",\n\"BTTTouchBarButtonColor\":\"75.323769, 75.323769, 75.323769, 255.000000\",\n\"BTTTouchBarAlwaysShowButton\":\"1\",\n\"BTTTouchBarAlternateBackgroundColor\":\"0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000\"\n}\n}";
    File f = new File("/Users/Andrew/Desktop/testfile.txt");
    try {f.createNewFile();}catch(Exception e){}
    addAction("open 'btt://add_new_trigger/?json="+action+"'");
  }

}
```

Edit: I am using JDK Version 8-171 for Mac

Comment: *"`import java.nio.*;` should import the second class anyway"* No. A wildcard import will only import types from the given package, not sub-packages, so it will **not** import `java.nio.file.Paths`. --- Full path of `Files` is `java.nio.file.Files`, so if you only import `java.nio.*` and `java.nio.file.Paths`, then you're not importing `Files` at all.

Comment: Why are you mixing [`java.io.File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) (old API) and [`java.nio.file.Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) (new API)? For any new code (i.e. code written for Java 7 or later), you should only use `Path`, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java compiler is getting confused because Files is the name of your class so it is looking for a write method in your class. Try leaving only this import :

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
```

And then call the complete class name for java.nio.file.Files:

```
java.nio.file.Files.write(Paths.get("/Users/Andrew/Desktop/testfile.txt"), text.getBytes());
```

But then you should handle your IOException also. Add your import and try/catch. Here is your class with no compilation errors:

```
import java.io.File; // Find Files
import java.io.IOException;

import java.awt.FileDialog; // File Picker

import javax.swing.JFrame; // JFrame

import java.nio.file.Paths;

class Files {

  public static void getApps(final File folder) {
      for (final File file : folder.listFiles()) {
           String fileName = file.getName();
           // System.out.println(fileName);
           // System.out.println(file.getPath());
          final File subfolder = new File(file.getPath()+"/Contents/Resources");
          if (subfolder.exists()) {
              String icon = pickFile(subfolder.getPath());
              if (icon == null) return;
              System.out.println("App Name: " + fileName);
              System.out.println("Icon Name: " + icon);
          } else {
              System.out.println("Directory not found...");
          }
      }
  }

public static String pickFile(String path) {
    FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(new JFrame(), "Select File to Open");
    dialog.setMode(FileDialog.LOAD);
    dialog.setFilenameFilter((File dir, String name) -> name.endsWith(".icns"));
    dialog.setDirectory(path);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    String fileChosen = dialog.getFile();
    return fileChosen;
}

public static void addAction(String cmd) {
    String text = "Text to save to file";
    try{
    java.nio.file.Files.write( Paths.get("/Users/Andrew/Desktop/testfile.txt"), text.getBytes());

    }catch(IOException e){
         System.err.print("Handle your error!");
    }
} 

public static void main (String[] args) {
    String action = "{\n\"BTTTouchBarButtonName\":\"Messages\",\n\"BTTTriggerType\":629,\n\"BTTTriggerClass\":\"BTTTriggerTypeTouchBar\",\n\"BTTPredefinedActionType\":49,\n\"BTTPredefinedActionName\":\"Launch Application \\/ Open File \\/ Start Apple Script …\",\n\"BTTLaunchPath\":\"file:\\/\\/\\/Applications\\/Messages.app\",\n\"BTTEnabled2\":1,\n\"BTTUUID\":\"F3089B96-FDEF-4D54-9DA8-9CCD3C7AF8A9\",\n\"BTTEnabled\":1,\n\"BTTRequiredModifierKeys\":1048576,\n\"BTTOrder\":1,\n   \"BTTIconData\":\"icondata\",\n\"BTTTriggerConfig\":{\n\"BTTTouchBarItemIconHeight\":22,\n\"BTTTouchBarItemIconWidth\":22,\n\"BTTTouchBarItemPadding\":0,\n\"BTTTouchBarFreeSpaceAfterButton\":\"5.000000\",\n\"BTTTouchBarButtonColor\":\"75.323769, 75.323769, 75.323769, 255.000000\",\n\"BTTTouchBarAlwaysShowButton\":\"1\",\n\"BTTTouchBarAlternateBackgroundColor\":\"0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000\"\n}\n}";
    File f = new File("/Users/Andrew/Desktop/testfile.txt");
    try {f.createNewFile();}catch(Exception e){}
    addAction("open 'btt://add_new_trigger/?json="+action+"'");
    }

}
```

Comment: 2022 not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a JAVA project and the class was written in Kotlin (copy-paste), so I added Kotlin dependencies and the problem is solved.